# Symfony form that generates another form

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a controller action the prompts the user for some free text input. When submitted the text is parsed into some number of objects that I want to put out on another form for the user to confirm that the initial parsing was done correctly.

Normally after dealing with the response to a form submission we call `$this->redirectToRoute()` to go off to some other path but I have all these objects laying around that I want to use. If I redirect off someplace else I lose them.

How can I keep them? I tried building my new form right there in the controller action method but then its submission does not seem to be handled properly.

```
/**
 * @Route( "/my_stuff/{id}/text_to_objects", name="text_to_objects" )
 */
public function textToObjects( Request $request, Category $category ) {
    $form = $this->createForm( TextToObjectsFormType::class, [
                    'category' => $category,
                    ]);
    $form->handleRequest( $request );
    if( $form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() ) {
        $formData = $form->getData();
        $allTheStuff = textParserForStuff( $formData['objectText'] );
        $nextForm = $this->createForm( StuffConfirmationFormType::class, $allTheStuff );
        return $this->render( 'my_stuff/confirmation.html.twig', [
            'form' => $nextForm->createView(),
            'category' => $category,
        ] );
    }
    return $this->render( 'my_stuff/text.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'category' => $category,
    ] );
}
```

This does fine to the point of displaying the confirmation form but when I submit that form I just end up displaying the original **TextToObjects** form?

To answer albert's question, the **TextToObjectsFormType** just has three fields, a way to set the date & time for the group of generated objects, a way to select the origin of the objects and a textarea for the textual description. I do not set a data_class so I get an associative array back with the submitted information.

```
class TextToObjectsFormType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options ) {
        $builder
        ->add( 'textSourceDateTime', DateTimeType::class, [
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'invalid_message' => 'Not a valid date and time',
                    'attr' => [ 'placeholder' => 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm',
                                'class' => 'js-datetimepicker', ],
                    ])
        ->add( 'objectsOrigin', EntityType::class, [ 
                    'class' => ObjectSourcesClass::class,
                    ])
        ->add( 'objectText', TextareaType::class, [
                    'label' => 'Copy and paste object description text here',
                    ]);           
    }
}
```

How can I get the confirmed, potentially revised, objects back to put them into the database?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code of TextToObjectsFormType ?

Answer (score 0):

Using your current architecture 
`$nextForm = $this->createForm( StuffConfirmationFormType::class, $allTheStuff );`
does not bear enough information. It should contain the action parameter to tell the submission to where route the post request.

In your StuffConfirmationFormType add an 'objectText' field hidden.

- Create a `confirmation_stuff` route
- Create an action for this route
- In this action if the form is valid => save your stuff ELSE re render `TextToObjectsFormType` with an action linked to `text_to_objects`

Be aware that using this technique would not prevent a user to enter non functional data by manually editing the hidden field.

Hope this helps